# how to edit {{form|crispy}} with css and move the forms around?

Tags: python, django

I've been using {{form|crispy}} but now that I have decided to design and move stuff around, I'm trying to edit my forms. 
I just have

```
{% block content %}
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
<!--{% for tag in person.tags.all %}{{ tag.word }} {% endfor %}-->

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Post">
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

in my html file.

I have

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

#   category = CategoryChoices()

    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="plz enter")

    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200,
                         help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.", required=False)
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        widgets = {
            'category':Select2Widget,
        }
        exclude = ['pub_date', 'moderator', 'rank_score','slug', 'image']
```

and in models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    video = EmbedVideoField(verbose_name='My video',blank=True, null=True)  

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='default')
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default= 1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',blank=True, null=True)
```

So in short I have:category, url, video link, title, content in my form. I'm trying to move these forms around. How do I achieve this goal? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the option of rendering the whole form together you can also render each element of the form seperately. I recommend to read through this part of the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually). 
For example you can do something like this:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Email subject:</label>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
```

For styling the form, I add CSS classes to the `fields` in the `__init__`function of my `Form` class . For example with your `PostForm` this could look something like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field_name in self.fields:
        field = self.fields[field_name]
        field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

This would assign the bootstrap class `form-control` to every field in your form. Of course you can also style individual fields using this method:

```
self.fields['title'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'This is a title'})
```

There might be better solutions for the styling part. Especially with bigger forms this could get a little clunky. But for the smaller forms i am handling right now it works just fine.